# Demander des nouvelles par email dans un cadre professionnel

Tags: sens, formulation

Bonjour, au travail, le chargé de clientèle m'a demandé, par email, d'effectuer un travail pour un client. Je lui demande des choses que le client doit nous fournir. Il me fait savoir qu'il revient vers moi dès qu'il a du nouveau.

Quelques jours plus tard et sans réponse de la part du chargé de clientèle, je dois lui faire un email pour savoir où on en est.
j'ai pensé à mettre:

```
Bonjour Matt,

Je reviens vers toi pour les nouvelles.

A+
```

Je ne sais pas si `Je reviens vers toi pour les nouvelles` veux dire ce que j'ai expliqué précédemment et si c'est bizarre ou pas.

J'espère avoir bien formulé :). Merci

**UPDATE1**

J'ai oublié de préciser que le contexte est connu car je réponds à une discussion, donc l'interlocuteur a tout l'historique. C'est donc voulu d'être un peu vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La phrase utilisée

> Je reviens vers toi pour les nouvelles.

ne me parait pas très naturelle et un peu floue sur le sujet de la demande.

La proposition suivante est très personnelle et loin d'être la seule possibilité, j'utiliserais plutôt,

> Je viens aux nouvelles concernant "les choses à fournir", peux tu me donner un état d'avancement ?

Cela a l'avantage de rappeler le sujet concerné pour éviter à Matt un effort de mémoire ou de relecture des mails précédent.

---

Suite à l'édition de la question, si le contexte est évident et dans un cadre de discussion avec un collègue:

> Je viens aux nouvelles, où en es tu ?

Dans le cas d'une communication avec un client, j'utiliserais plutôt le vouvoiement à moins de connaitre personnellement l'interlocuteur.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse, j'ai mis à jour ma question. Nous nous tutoyons dans mon entreprise, donc pas de problème à ce niveau.

Comment: Je pensais que le mail s'adressait à un client et non a un collègue :)

Comment: Désolé, je viens d'expliciter ceci dans ma question.

Comment: @smarber pas de soucis j'ai adapté ma réponse :)

Answer (score 3):

Si c'est nécessaire, on peut être plus formel que le simple mais efficace *où en es-tu ?*, par exemple:

> N'ayant pas vu de retour sur le sujet, je me permets une relance.

Answer (score 1):

*Pour les nouvelles* n'est pas adapté ici puisque justement, il n'y en a pas.

Voici trois propositions:

Je reviens vers toi pour...

- avoir des nouvelles;
- savoir s'il y a du nouveau;
- savoir si tu as pu avancer sur ce que je t'ai demandé.

Attention, il ne doit pas y avoir de majuscule à ***je*** puisqu'il suit une virgule.

Comment: Le but en fait est plutôt pour relancer cette personne. Mais je voulais mettre autre chose que "Je me permets de te relancer concernant blabla", ou encore "Je reviens vers toi au sujet de blabla". Vous dites que ce n'est pas adapté, mais est-ce que ça se dit? N'est-ce pas bizarre? Est-ce naturel?

Comment: Non, un francophone ne dirait pas *Je reviens vers toi pour les nouvelles*, on comprend l'intention mais ce n'est pas idiomatique.